# convert XML to JSON in Java with child nodes as array

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm looking for a way to convert an XML to JSON in Java in a way such that child nodes will alway be converted to an array.
In Node.js there's the library [XmlToJs](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js).

The use case is when I have an XML like the following:

XML:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>data</C>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C>data1</C>
    <C>data2</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

JSON with [org.json](http://www.json.org/) conversion:

```
{
  "A": {
      "B": [{
          "C": "data"
      }, {
          "C": ["data1", "data2"]
      }]
   }
}
```

what I would like for the conversion to yield:

```
{
  "A": {
      "B": [{
          "C": ["data"]
      }, {
          "C": ["data1", "data2"]
      }]
   }
}
```

Comment: Question is a common one, is asked well, and one that I have not seen clearly answered online.  Usually people point you to a basic guide for how to convert XML to JSON whereas this question refers to a common problem that occurs AFTER you've already accomplished this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library and static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. There is a special attribute `array="true"` which forces element to be an array. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C array="true">data</C>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C>data1</C>
    <C>data2</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Output:

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": [
      {
        "C": [
          "data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "C": [
          "data1",
          "data2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above can be done but probably not directly i.e. XML -> JSON, one approach s to have an intermediate object representation of the data model then XML -> Data Model -> JSON. The XML-> Data Model can be achieved with JAXB providers in the structure required, once the data is in the model you could serialize it to JSON

Comment: but what if I don't know the schema of the xml. It should operate on every type of XML input

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jackson XML to do this. Here's a blog post that explains what to do https://dzone.com/articles/solving-the-xml-problem-with-jackson

Comment: I don't think it is clear which part of this article solves the 'object as array' problem that the question refers to.